# MEDIUMBLOB(image) in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, blob

I have a restored database in MS SQL Server 2005 that has some tables with fields of datatype MEDIUMBLOB(image)

First thing I dont understand is I can't create a field with this data type in a new database. MEDIUMBLOB is not available in the data type selection drowpdown.

Second is, how do I read this field from C#? I know there is XML data stored in this field.

[image: MediumBlob in SQL Server]

Comment: Have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047099/read-mediumblob-data-type-from-mysql-in-c-sharp

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a `MEDIUMBLOB` data type .... furthermore, the `image` datatype in SQL Server is **deprecated** and should not be used anymore - use `VARBINARY(MAX)` instead to handle binary blob style data

Comment: i-kiet I'm not talking about MySQL.

Comment: marc-s I thought the same, but as you can see in the screenshot,  this guys have somehow enabled it in SQL Server 2005. How is this possible??

Comment: Check further down in the `Types` folder, there will be a type definition of `MEDIUMBLOB` as a varbinary(xyz). SQL Server allows you to define `types` as aliases for specific raw type definitions. Or it may be a CLR type

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server allows you to create aliases for native types with the [CREATE TYPE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007.aspx) command. The image shows that the column is defined as a `MEDIUMBLOB` with an underlying native type of `image`.

CREATE TYPE can also be used to create user-defined types defined in CLR assemblies